# undefined reference to `sd_notify'

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, notifications

I have a process which creates a lot of processes, I want to identify(get the pid) of one of the children. Looping through children would take a lot of resources(don't ask why). SO I'm trying to get the pid of process by (somehow) identifying if it uses `sd_notify` and get the pid(I don't really now if its possible). I'm using ubuntu 14.04 and created little test program:

```
#include <systemd/sd-daemon.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int a;
  a = sd_notify(0, "READY=1");
  printf("%d -> \n", a);
  fflush(stdout);
}
```

But it gives me error saying `undefined reference to 'sd_notify'`.

**P.S**
I found that `sd_notify` is for systemd systems. What is the equivalent of this in upstart systems? Or how can I make sure that the process I'm searching doen't use this function? Or is it possible to log all the messages that is send by processes using `sd_notify`?

Comment: Seems a bit like [the XY problem] (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - why do you believe that you will able to identify a process just because it uses `sd_notify`? Why do you need to get the PID of this particular child at all?

Comment: What I'm actually trying is that, I'm logged in as user A, create process as user B, and that process creates session for user B, (`/etc/X11/Xsession 'gnome-session --session=ubuntu'`) I'm trying to get dbus connection name (from dbus-daemon --session) from that process of user B's session and log out user.

Comment: ok, then that's the question you should have asked. :) (and with much detail added, because there a lot of things that are still unclear about the limitations of what you're doing. Why not use the standard DBus APIs - either systemd or consolekit - to locate the session?)

Comment: I'm trying to make my program work on every distro(systemd, upstart init). I haven't tried using any APIs. So you think that this method would not help me identify the pid?

Comment: Or could you please provide how can I get the pid or log out other user using `Consolekit`?

Comment: comments are not for extended discussion. If you have another question, ask it by posting a question. "So you think that this method would not help me identify the pid?" - I don't understand how you think it _could_ let you identify the pid, and you haven't explained that. Maybe you haven't explained well enough, or maybe this is a case of the XY problem; in either case, ask another question, start from the beginning, explain thoroughly, don't make assumptions, and you should get helpful answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try installing `libsystemd-daemon-devel` and then compile using

`g++ -o sig sig.cpp -lsystemd-daemon`

Comment: Thanks very much, it worked. Could you please tell me if its possible to log all the messages that is send by processes using sd_notify? Or is it place anywhere that it gets logged? thanks again.

Comment: @Rasty I haven't used this library before so can't comment. Suggest you to ask another question for that. Please accept this answer if it helped you. Thanks!

Comment: for me `sudo apt-get install libsystemd-dev`and appending `-lsystemd` worked on kubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 2):

You're not linking to the required library at compilation time. Try adding the option `-lsystemd` to your compilation command line.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I'm using `g++ -o sig sig.cpp -l systemd`

Comment: No space - `-lsystemd` - is conventional (not sure if it is actually necessary).

Comment: Space or no space makes no difference, both allowed