# Ubuntu 22.04 Undefined reference to 'sd_notify'

Tags: ubuntu-22.04, gcc12

I am trying to build something I need which I downloaded from:
https://github.com/izot/lon-driver

Unfortunately the build instructions are non-existent and there doesn't appear to be a way to ask for assistance either.

I have downloaded using git to my virtual machine which is Ubuntu 22.04, I am trying to compile the file in *lonifd* using:

```
gcc lonifd.c
```

The result is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccJleZ8s.o: in function `main':
lonifd.c:(.text+0x3882): undefined reference to `sd_notify'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've search around for solutions and have updated gcc which is now:

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

git version: `git version 2.34.1`

Comment: Maybe [this info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38303241/7644018) might help?

Comment: @PaulT., thank you, found that before I posted, it didn't help, mainly because it comes up with "cannot find -lsystemd_daemon: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install:
libsystemd-dev

Then
gcc lonifd.c -lsystemd

should work (tested on ubuntu 18.04)